# Excel Lookup and pull in depending on cell contents

Tags: excel, vlookup

Another tricky issue for me.

I have worksheet with all my information. On another sheet I need to pull a number depending on a specific value. for example:

On the Master sheet,

```
Cell AN2 will contain either BMI or ASCAP
Cell A2 will contain a number, let's say 12345
```

On my Second sheet, I have two columns; AJ2 for BMI# and AM2 for the ASCAP#

I need to look at the Master sheet, decide if A2 is a BMI or ASCAP number (from AN2) and put it in the correct cell on the Second sheet.

I know this is a Vlookup function, but I can't get it to work. I did a search and read through some of the answers, but still can't get it to work.

Thanks for all the great info here.

Using Excel 15 on MacOS

Comment: What's your `VlookUp()` formula? Have you tried `Index/Match`? Perhaps `=If([index/match formula]="BMI#",[index/match number],"")`.

Comment: I don't know - as I have tried so many different combinations with the vlookup, got frustrated and deleted them all. I am totally new to all this excel advanced functions, so it makes my eyes glass over after a while. I will look into the index/match functions, but right now that is all greek to me.

Comment: Hm - from what I can see, put this in your Second Sheet, AJ2 and AM2 (assuming AJ1 and AM1 are headers "BMI" and "ASCAP"): `=IF(Master!$AN$2=AJ$1,Master!$A$2,"")` ...is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: I can see kind of what you are doing there, but it only returns a 0 in the cell and not the number from MasterA2. If I understand that formula, you are saying: look at cell AN2 on the master sheet. If that "word" match the same on on the Second sheet in AJ1, fill in the value from Master A2. - right? Is that what the $ signs mean in the reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put this formula into your second sheet in AJ2:

```
=IF(Master!AN2="BMI",Master!A2,"")
```

And this in AN2:

```
=IF(Master!AN2="ASCAP",Master!A2,"")
```

And copy those values down, it should work.  This will, of course, only populate one of the two for any given row, but based on your description it sounds like that's what you wanted.

And of course if your sheet isn't literally named "Master," change it to whatever the sheet name actually is.